# Reading numbers and unevaluated statements from a file

Tags: c++, file-io, input, output

I have a general file which constructs certain shapes and I would like to read in the lines:

```
0    0      1
0    x(r)   y(r)
```

where `x` and `y` are functions of `r`, which is a variable taken in as an argument to main, such as `2*r-4`.

Then I need to read the columns downwards into arrays.

For columns with just numbers you can do something like:

```
file >> x[j];
```

However I am unsure how to get the expressions to be read into the program and then be evaluated and then be put into an array as a number.

I am having problems reading in columns with entries of different types. Ideally I would like each to be assigned like:

```
temp[0]=1;
temp[1]=2*r-4;
```

but I am not sure how to do this.

(I am not sure whether the function `fscanf` would work?)

Comment: You could make all the rows interpreted as std::function<int(int)>, where constants are just lamda functions `[x](int r){return x}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read an entire line with `file.getline(someString, maxLength)`. Then you can split the string so you have strings for `x(r)` and `y(r)`. These strings need to be parsed as mathematical expressions. This question has good information on the subject for c++: [Convert string to mathematical evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439295/convert-string-to-mathematical-evaluation)